# Updating the listview tile data(not item) lively(constantly) flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, dynamic, refresh

I have created a listview with tiles containing title and buy price and sell price (Text widgets).I build the list view from Rest API call and initially all the price values of every tile will be set to zero. then, I call SSE and receive live data for the price values.what I am trying to define is, only the price values(Title will remain static) of every tiles should be constantly updated. does the listview of the flutter support this kind of action ? I am new to flutter.can somebody help me by answering if it is possible ?
if so how to do it (a general idea).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you, what are the components you want to change.

A simple approach is to update the list(not listview) by which you are populating the listtiles inside listview and then call the setState.

You can update the list by changing the cost of each item of your custom data type in the list or you can also change the complete list item (possibly this is not required in question).

Comment: I got an idea and did it but thanks for helping I appreciate it.